# Is there a way to automate access to metadata in Tableau?

Tags: metadata, tableau-api, api-design

I am looking to **automate accessing the metadata of workbooks in Tableau** **to house all the metadata in a separate table which could then be queried for search purposes**.

I heard that REST API could be used to do the above stated but haven't really found a concrete evidence. **If anyone has come across a way to automatically access the metadata from Tableau** , please guide me.

Comment: Show what have you tried so far

Comment: Can you give some specific metadata examples you are looking for?

Comment: @SamM I am actually looking for the name of the workbook, hierarchy, description and if possible the field names which were used to construct the report along with the metric level titles in the report.